# Filter Builder in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jqgrid, filter

Anyone knows a javascript alternative to something like:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Filtering/FilterBuilder.aspx
-> click on the condition in the footer of the grid to see the filter

Can be a jquery plugin, jqGrid plugin or anything.

Any suggestion appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is an open source project in Google Code, which meets your requirement. Checkout the demo here:
http://expbuilder.googlecode.com/hg/src/cb/condition-builder.html

Edit: Google Code is no longer active but if you're really interested in trying this old answer, you can download the source code here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/expbuilder/source/default/source

Comment: Download link would be convenient :D.

Answer (score 0):

I checked Paramesh solution and found it good enough for me.

However while integrating with project, I found js is rather lacking more modern jQuery features, as well as it can be simplified. So I did.

My alternative solution:

https://github.com/Drachenfels/sql-like-query-builder-for-js

With demo:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/196245/condition-builder/condition-builder.html

Maybe someone will find it useful some day.

Feel free to copy/paste/change/suggest fixes/suggest features. ;)

Answer (score 0):

[DevExtreme](https://js.devexpress.com/) recently released js Filter Builder widget, and it works in different approaches and jQuery also supported. You can see [Filter Builder Demo](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/FilterBuilder/WithDataGrid/jQuery/Light/)